# Can I give a part or full of my zakat to my father who has debt

Tags: zakat, debt

Can I give a part or full of my zakat to my father who has debt and its increasing day by day for high interest rates.

Answer (score 1):

> They ask you (O Muhammad SAW) what they should spend. Say: Whatever you spend of good must be for parents and kindred and orphans and Al-Masakin (the poor) and the wayfarers, and whatever you do of good deeds, truly, Allah knows it well.
>   <sub>[Surah Baqarah Ayah 215](http://quran.com/2/215)</sub>

Yes, you can give your full Zakah to your father until your father's debts are cleared off, or until he is able to bear his expenses by himself.

References:

<sub>[Can a mother give zakat to her unemployed and poor son?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23574/9123)</sub>

<sub>[Is giving zakat to a family member allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1607/9123)</sub>

<sub>[Are you allowed to give zakat to your parents or wife?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9764/9123)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Zakat cannot be given to either of the parents. However, you may pay off your father’s debt from your money and that will be considered as sadaqa (charity).

My brother, if you have the money to pay off your father’s debt, please pay it off. Releasing a person from his debt is a highly appreciated by Allah. And since he is your father and you have the money, please by all means assist him.

And Allah Knows Best.